# How to make doInBackground() wait for another function in AyncTask class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a custom AsyncTask class which checks if the device has granted permission to location, and then it gets the last known location. If it has no permission, it asks the user for permission first. So in my doInBackground function, I need to call mGoogleApiClient.connect() and this will trigger onConnected function. As can be seen, doInBackground needs to wait for onConnected, otherwise it return null object lastKnownLocation. My question is how do I make doInBackground wait for onConnected?

```
public class GetLocationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Location> implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
    , GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location lastKnownLocation = null; //In case the users reject location permission request, we might initialize the location to something interesting
public AsyncResponseForLocation delegate = null;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;

public GetLocationTask(Activity activity, Context context) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Location doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    return lastKnownLocation;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    lastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Location location) {
    delegate.processFinish(location);
}


public interface AsyncResponseForLocation {

void processFinish(Location location);}
```

Comment: I can not use while(lastKnownLocation == null) {} to wait for the object as this object might be null in some case.

Comment: Check [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and use `get` to "Waits if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result."

Comment: I found a way around this finally. But also thanks to Lior for pointing out the work flow problem.
I created a variable private boolean onConnectedCompleted = false;
and in onConnected(), I add onConnectedCompleted = true; on the last time. Then in my doInBackground I just need to check this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Timertask which runs every 5sec for checking condition isConnected() .

Try below code

```
   private void startTimer(){
            mTimer1 = new Timer();
            mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run(){
                            if(isConnected){

                            //call the Async task
                               }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

        mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 1, 5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your `doInBackground()` method. `AsyncTask()` will first execute `onPreExecute()` and then `doInBackground()`.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // your code hear
    }
```